# Goodbye for now

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

**TL;DR:** I will not be participating on this or any other Stack Exchange for at least the next several months, if I return at all. I'm sure y'all can do just fine without me.

---

The past few months have really been something, haven't they?

I think we can all agree that Stack Exchange has done a truly disastrous job of rolling out the pronouns policy, regardless of our opinions of it. This is in many ways the culmination of years of broken trust between the community and the company.

Unfortunately, that's not why I'm leaving.

Frankly, I get it. Stack Exchange is a for-profit company. Sometimes they do things in the interest of profit-chasing that are really not in the interest of the community. At times they have done a poor job of balancing those concerns. But as any company or organization grows, it inevitably becomes harder to steer from both the top and the bottom, as middle management begins taking over the day-to-day operations at both ends. So while I was hardly pleased with Stack Exchange's development into a "mature" company, I did not find it particularly alarming or surprising.

What I did find alarming was the scale at which members of our community are either ambivalent towards or outright opposed to diversity and inclusion, both in general and with respect to trans folks in particular. I observed people openly arguing that they should be allowed to intentionally misgender others, that anyone who feels strongly about gender is mentally ill, and that diversity does not represent a real problem for the software industry.

I have serious reservations about working alongside people who espouse such ideas. It destroys my trust. I realize that many of you prefer to set our differences aside and ignore these disagreements. I'm sure that works very well for you. But I cannot continue to abide it.

That brings me to Monica and the TL. In an ideal world, I could just refrain from mentioning her, and y'all would understand that I have nothing to say on the topic. We don't live in an ideal world. If I don't mention her, then you'll start reading all sorts of things into what I said above, and draw wild conclusions that I did not intend. So I'll say a few words about her. When I first heard that she got fired, before we non-diamond peons knew any of the details, I was positively livid. In the public spaces that I can see, she has been an exemplary moderator, consistently embodying the [ideal archetype](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) and serving as a standard-bearer for other moderators. She was alleged to have broken some ill-defined rule in the TL, which certainly sounded like an unreasonable excuse to globally revoke a diamond.

Then I learned that many of the people who were telling us about the TL are also people I no longer trust. People who espouse those hateful beliefs I described above.

A conspiracy to lie about what happened in the TL? Of course not, that's absurd on its face. There would be far too many participants for such a scheme to work, and I assume that the majority of moderators, regardless of their individual beliefs, would not stoop to such dishonorable behavior.

However, I cannot escape the feeling that many of the moderators involved could have allowed their beliefs about the situation to color their interpretation of the discussion. We don't have a verbatim transcript, just the subjective opinions of various people who were there, sometimes filtered through the third-hand interpretations of non-mods (like me). I also know that multiple people have claimed that Monica did hurt some feelings, albeit (one presumes) unintentionally. Monica has now quite publicly demanded an apology and retraction from Stack Exchange, which they have curiously failed to give her considering how little it would cost them (and considering that they have *already apologized* for other aspects of the situation). The corporate fog of war is one thing, but it sounds as if she is about to lawyer up (if she hasn't already), and you would really expect SE to act in defense of their own best interests here.

So, my conclusion is that I don't have enough information to know what to think. I could speculate, but there is absolutely no point, because I know I won't change anyone's mind. I'm not trying to. I'm just saying, in a very long-winded way, that I don't have any particular opinion about Monica's situation, I find it hard to believe that she has espoused any of the openly hateful views I described above, and I don't expect any argument to convince me of anything else, short of a verbatim, authenticated transcript of the whole TL exchange that got her fired. Who knows, if this goes to court, we might even get to see that one day. Regardless of how that shakes out, Monica has nothing to do with my decision to leave, and I wish her well.

**The bottom line:** I don't trust y'all anymore. I'm sorry, but there's really no way to sugarcoat it. This isn't about any individual members of the community. This is about the community as a whole. For the sake of my own mental health, I'm taking a break of indefinite length. Maybe I'll come back one day, but not any time soon. In the meantime, I sincerely wish you all the best, regardless of how you feel about these issues.

This isn't a question, so feel free to close it if y'all don't actually care.

Comment: "The corporate fog of war is one thing, but it sounds as if she is about to lawyer up (if she hasn't already)" She lawyered up back at the end of [October](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users), but that's neither here nor there. Sorry to see you go, but I get it. Good luck in your pursuits outside of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @samuelLiew ... a bit ironic to create a new tag "participation" for this question ... but I get you don't want to call it "non-participation" .....

Comment: Wow...I don't even know what to say. *"I observed people openly arguing that they should be allowed to intentionally misgender others, that anyone who feels strongly about gender is mentally ill, and that diversity does not represent a real problem for the software industry."* Where in the world have you observed such things? I haven't seen anything like that, save for maybe one or two isolated incidents. Are there a lot of people upset by the way that Stack Overflow rolled out new policies? Yes. I'm one of them. But I *certainly* don't believe any of those things you claim to have observed.

Comment: @CodyGray Especially not here, on Stack Overflow (Meta). On SE Meta, maybe. Or in SE chat rooms (which I do not follow, at all). If this were on SE Meta, I could somewhat understand...

Comment: I've seen a lot of _discussion_ on MSE. For many users (esp non-native speakers) this topic was completely new, so that could have been expected. Social change needs time, and it is really difficult to enforce it with a preparation time of zero, so we should give people some time to understand. But what I didn't see is an alarming scale of users being outright opposed.

Comment: @CodyGray If you have 10k on MSE and absolutely feel like destroying some of your faith in humanity, venture in the now deleted original CoC FAQ on MSE. Or don't, because it's a depressing read.

Comment: I've read every single one of them, @mag, and those handful of bigoted answers there are the isolated incidents to which I refer. I certainly don't think that speaks for the community at large, and if you're going to leave Stack Exchange for that, well, you're going to have to leave the world, because it's a *lot* worse out there.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't disagree, but following the post and its comments as they came in, I saw all three sentiments outlined above. Not often, but present nonetheless. Most of the people who spouted them were suspended or had their posts deleted as r/a

Comment: Yes, and I think that speaks to the general sentiments of the community.

Comment: It's time to reject the notion of "the community". There is no such thing, it is a non-existent entity. There may be communities, plural. Likeminded people will always seek each other out to gain strength in numbers. You may be severely disappointed by **a** community - but let's face it, the reality is more that it are loud individuals that are to blame here that mingle and swarm all around - or stay hidden in the background. It is woefully unfair to cast the net this wide.

Comment: Also all the best. It's important to read similar voices, even though I don't fully agree. How can one not trust everyone? I don't even know everyone here. And with time others will go too and new people will come.

Comment: Related: [Aza's resignation post](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/resignation-notice) - Note that this was prior to Monica's resignation so the bigotry being referred to is not about the community reaction to the Code of Conduct changes.

Answer (score 19):

> What I did find alarming was the scale at which members of our community are either ambivalent towards or outright opposed to diversity and inclusion, both in general and with respect to trans folks in particular

I think this is a core problem. If you are ambivalent, if you have doubts about the current inclusion and diversion policy, you are a transphobe.

If I find it wrong to demand from every user, no matter what native language they have, what culture they come from, to be ready to use neopronouns correctly, am I a transphobe? If I tell a user that they should better research their question and could perform some google search before asking, I am considered rude and unwelcoming. But neopronouns are mandatory on demand, because everyone can google them easily. And it turns out that pointing this as inconsistency is transphobic.

**UPDATE**
It seems that my example concern above got more attention that I expected. The main question is "am I allowed to have doubts"?
My main concern about diversity policy is: I expected SO to focus on content and sharing knowledge. I feel the recent policy pushes toward focusing on human relations. And I believe it's wrong and harmful for the site. Main target of SO content are neither askers nor answerers, but google users who find already answered questions. If someone [wants to exit vim editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor), they don't care if jclancy or dirvine are binary, non-binary octal or hexadecimal. If they find any discussion about proper pronouns, they will consider it noise.
Moreover, I agree that you should not address anyone as they do not want to. But the policy goes much further. The part about "conspicuously avoiding using pronouns". I understand that if family members conspicuously avoid ones pronouns  it is wrong and hurtful. But we are not anyone's family here. If you notice someone conspicuously avoiding your pronouns, you engaged too much. Let's address content, not persons.
When I raise the concern about conspicuously avoiding pronouns I get answer, that I should not fear as this will be applied reasonably and in normal site usage I will never encounter such situation. Well, we have one example of this policy in action and it happened even before this policy was announced. Monica Cellio. Well, this example does not make me optimistic about reasonable application of this rule.

So I think that we should focus on content, not persons. That this is not social network and focusing on relations here brings more harm than good. I think that diversity support in knowledge base means ensuring that knowledge is as good as possible and is available to everybody, regardless their gender, country, religion etc. Not making knowledge base sources coming from diverse enough sources. Does this make me transphobe or bigot?

Comment: The only thing that's required is using right pronouns when asked. If you get it wrong by accident, that doesn't put you in a "transphobe" box. But if after being corrected someone refuses to use the appropriate pronouns, well, they are certainly not being kind.

Comment: @yivi You are addressing concerns of someone who has a problem with using neopronouns. I have concerns about demanding using neopronouns. It is a meta-concern.

Comment: The demand is to be kind and inclusive. This logically requires the use of certain language, and prohibits the use of another kind of language. I can understand why someone would not like, to put it mildly, that the wrong pronouns are used for them. I can't understand why is such an important issue for everybody else. They are just words. If using certain words make other people feel better, and using other words make other people feel hurt... what's the big deal? What is there to be "ambivalent" about?

Comment: @yivi, yours is an argument that occurs a lot in this kind of discussion -- *doing X is important for group Y but shouldn't be important for everybody else, so why being ambivalent over it?* However, there may be people outside of group Y who are not confortable at all doing X, and by that reasoning they are not *allowed* to express that, lest them be considered as Y-phobe scum. This, I believe, is the crux of our current problem.

Comment: Hey, the main point is not if my concern is valid. The main point is am I allowed to have concerns without being transphobic. I picked one that I could describe quickly as this question may get closed very quickly. If you want to hear more concerns I can add them.

Comment: I'm sorry @Frédéric, but I haven't seen an argument that I found reasonable for anyone not being "_comfortable_" using the right pronouns. And again, the demand is to be kind and inclusive. This is just a specific implementation detail.

Comment: @yivi, I understand that you think such arguments are not reasonable, but they do exist, and they are important to the people making them. As important as, say, being addressed with the right pronouns is to other people. If you want a specific example, look no further than religious reasons. Tolerance is a two-way street, being intolerant to some people on the basis you believe they're intolerant to others is a nasty catch-22, as recent events have proven.

Comment: I have no problem with religious people, @Frédéric. But religious people still need to live in the world. They can all believe anything they want, but they are still subject to the rules of the land. Language included. And codes of conduct included. If someone can't accommodate their beliefs to the rules of the land, I'm sorry but the onus is on them. I have my own beliefs that run against certain laws and regulations in the real world, and I know where and how I can express those beliefs without hitting trouble.

Comment: @yivi, this discussion is interesting, I hope it will remain. I'm not a religious person myself, nor am I a member of the lavender community, but I respect both, and I honestly have a hard time understanding why the opinions of one group should be ignored in favor of the opinions of another. That doesn't seem fair to me. In addition, the "rules of the land" you speak of are only enforced in a tiny part of the world right now -- it is understandable the rest of us are dumbfounded by the current drama (and collateral damage) about enforcing them here.

Comment: @yivi To play devil's advocate here: *"They can all believe anything they want, but they are still subject to the rules of the land."* – Yes, this goes exactly the other way around as well. It is virtually impossible to use language *without* blaspheming against some religion or another. Whatever you say, eventually you're sure to offend *someone* with it. Yet most religious people manage to live "in the land" without being offended about it left and right. They adapt to the non-religious/people of other religions, even if they'd probably prefer others to use certain language differently…

Comment: You are right @deceze. But there is no religion that is "the rule of the land" here on SO. We can all say blasphemous things unless we are trying to hurt or marginalize other users. Or if we correct our language when asked about, because the golden rule is still "be kind and inclusive". I won't use expressions like "damnation!", or invoke the name of the Prophet, to name a couple of naive examples. And if someone points me to something I said and tell me that a particular expression is hurtful, I will try to amend it.

Comment: @yivi Yes, fair enough, that's as it should be. Live and let live. The concern others like Tadeusz are voicing here is that correct usage of pronouns is singled out and elevated above all else and more or less *demanded* now. Why doesn't it fall under the same category as not naming the prophet? Avoid it as a common measure of decency *as far as you're aware of the issue*, but don't *demand* it. There are innumerable such tiny issues in this world, and nobody can be expected to be aware of all of them. Are we going to address each of them in this same fashion henceforth?

Comment: @deceze because religion has enjoyed all kind of protections and exemptions since time immemorial; while being gender-inclusive is a relatively new thing that is still being fought about? It’s singled out because many feel it needs singling out; otherwise it won’t prosper. The same happens with any new concern of this type, even more so with concerns that face a very entrenched opposition in societal inertia. And despite the horrid first version of the pronouns FAQ, the demands are pretty lightweight. _Do not use the wrong pronouns for people, people._

Comment: @yivi But you do understand that this is something that *can* be debated about—whether it *is* necessary to single it out, and whether it's necessary to do it *here*—and that it should be possible to debate about that without being declared enemy number one (e.g. "transphobe")?

Comment: @deceze Frankly, I'm not sure what we need to "debate". We haven't debated every other single point of the CoC. I'm not sure why _this_ point is different.

Comment: @deceze I understand debating topicality and scope. Question quality and user interface changes. Voting weights and privileges thresholds. The rules that make for what the site owners define as necessary for inclusivity and kindness? Not so much.

Comment: @yivi I think we *did* discuss pretty much every other point of the [CoC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) ad nauseum since forever; random example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/476, which is basically a discussion about the very first point in the CoC.

Comment: @deceze I think that calling that part of the CoC is a stretch. While technically covered, it's not what the CoC was written to address. That's part of what I think we _should_ discuss, as I mention in my previous comment.

Comment: @yivi To quote: *"__Our Expectations__ If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. [Follow our guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers."* – Follow that link too. I think that's very much part of the CoC. And we have discussed that up and down and inside out for the past decade. If you disagree… well, then we're at a impasse. Which I think sums up Tadeusz point (not to put words in their mouth).

Comment: @deceze I had followed that link and read the CoC. And I mentioned that it was "technically covered". But can we agree that the CoC was enacted not to address that, which we already had rules for, but other type of behaviour? What the CoC address in the other 90% of that page? Which is expressing the vaguer "be nice" rules in a more explicit manner? If you want to say topicality discussion is equivalent to "be nice" enforcement, then as you say, we are at an impasse.

Comment: @yivi Yes, I’m saying we should be able to discuss every part of that, including detailed definitions of what “be nice” includes exactly. The only thing necessary here is to be able to talk about it. I’m not even saying anything about whether “be nice” or anything else should or shouldn’t be part of the CoC.

Comment: @deceze So we should expect the same kind discussion and opposition to not being able to call users "lazy", for example? We kinda dismiss users when they bring something like that up, or suspend them if they insist doing it.

Comment: @yivi The fact that nobody—as far as I’m aware—is complaining about *lazyphobes* when such discussions are shut down shows that there apparently isn’t a lot to discuss there. The fact that language usage keeps coming up shows that apparently there *is* something to discuss there. Why not allow it?

Comment: The fact that something "keeps coming up" does not show that we actually need to discuss anything, @deceze. We keep closing _"mandatory commetns on downvotes!!!1!!"_ or _"why can't I leave X type of comment?!?!?"_ no matter how often they appear. Some subjects to come up repeatedly, some subjects are hotter than others... If there is an actual "need" to discuss this, I haven't yet read an argument that convinced me. Noise or apparent frequency do not, for example. I could be convinced, I think, with the right argument.

Comment: @yivi Yes, these things do tend to come up again and again, because somebody feels it's a good idea, and we've discussed thoroughly (oh so very *very* thoroughly) why it's a bad idea. — The point of *this* thread is that discussions about pronouns tend to end in being shut down by some variation of ad hominem attacks, instead of discussing the point itself. If that isn't an argument that convinces you, then we're indeed at an impasse. I'll leave it at that. Perhaps somebody can derive some meaning from this exchange to see where exactly the crux lies in this debate.

Comment: @deceze "Why doesn't it fall under the same category as not naming the prophet?" Not exactly my concern. I rather ask why demand more research on pronouns than on actual question one wants to ask. BTW I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was slightly hijacking your cause there, sorry.  I do think we largely have the same concern though, and I certainly wholeheartedly agree with your extended answer. Worrying about gender is not primarily why I signed up for SO.

Comment: Thank you for that post, one of the most important ones on this issues in my regard. I always found it too much black and white that if you are not completely for the pronouns you cannot be one of the good ones anymore. This sounds too simple and even worse means that a lot of support that otherwise may exist is just ignored. You cannot hold a center position. You must either be for or against everything. I don't like such situations much.

Comment: *"But we are not anyone's family here"* - This is not said often enough. No, we're not. We really are not. In fact we're hardly better than random people passing by in the streets. Quite often silently. Maybe you acknowledge each other. Sometimes you ask a polite question. Offer voluntary assistance to someone in need. Maybe alert authority of wrongdoing / problems. You may bump into someone by accident. Every chance interaction with other people should not be a big deal; it's just a quick encounter that should pass as quickly as it presented itself. And then you go on with your life.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi [The mod message for my most recent suspension (a year's duration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyAM7.png)

Comment: @Robert, thanks for sharing this. For the record, I had the time to read your question, and although I can understand it rustled some feathers, calling it *incendiary* and *without any semblance of good faith* speaks volumes about the opinion differences between the remaining mods on MSE, myself, and most probably a good chunk of the community. I'm very sorry you got suspended over this, especially for so long. Take care.

Comment: @yivi "They are just words." You might like to rethink that sentence, because it can also be used against your argument. Words are an expression of thoughts, and if someone else is telling you what you can't (or must) say, that is tantamount to telling you what you can't (or must) think. So no, they're never just words.

Answer (score -2):

I've decided to return to Stack Exchange.

Given the cool reception of this question, and the overall hostility towards Diversity and Inclusion which I have repeatedly observed from members of this community, **I will not be returning to any of the Trilogy sites** (Stack Overflow, Super User, or Server Fault), and I will also minimize my participation on the other technical sites. I think this is the best path forward for everyone involved.

Administrivia:

- Anything in my inbox that originates from the Trilogy will be summarily ignored. Anything that originates from another technical site will be read, and then *probably* ignored.

  - Exception: If a moderator directly contacts me, *via email*, and specifically requests my input on any incident which somehow involves me, I will respond to that moderator privately. I do not actually expect this to happen, because I will not be participating on the site and do not expect to be involved in such incidents.
- For the purposes of this discussion, MSO and the other two per-site metas are also part of the Trilogy, and will also be ignored.
- My new home site will be [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com).
- If you believe you can improve any of my posts, please edit them yourself. Do not leave comments, because they will not be acted upon.
- As a courtesy, I will link to this answer from my per-site profiles on the Trilogy, so that people know I am not reading their comments. If y'all delete this question or answer, then those links will break, and I will not fix them (because they would have nowhere else to point anyway).